# Does radiation spread within a room or the entire vault?

Tags: fallout-shelter

If I send a dweller into the wasteland and they come back with radiation poisoning, or there is a radroach infestation, will the radiation poisoning spread to other dwellers in the same room as the poisoned dwellers or to all dwellers within my vault?

Also if it does spread, how is the rate of spread calculated?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/224167/all-dwellers-are-radiated-how-could-this-happen?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither. Dwellers in the vault take radiation damage where there isn't enough water. As long there is enough water, you don't have to worry about any radiation.

Dwellers in the Wasteland with less than 10 END will take Radiation damage over time. There is no risk of them passing this radiation damage on to other dwellers.

EDIT:
As of 1.1, wasteland explorers with END up to 12 take Rad damage, but so little they will use 25 stimpacks and die before they need a single Radaway

Comment: This is true with the exception of the people in the waste, they are just going to have their radiation levels go up over time regardless.. Having water in the vault though Will take care of it for them as well when they return.